# Why is /.+\[[0-9]+\]/g not correctly splitting "hello[0][1][3]"

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this regex: `/.+\[[0-9]+\]/g`
and this string `hello[0][1][3]`

And I am trying to split that into - `hello[0]`, `hello[0][1]` and `hello[0][1][3]` using `regex.exec(...)` but I am getting `hello[0][1][3]` as the only match.

How can I modify the regular expression to get the desired result

Comment: The regex in the question title is significantly different from the regex in the question text. Which is it?

Comment: .. because of how the regex starts ... `.+` is greedy and already does match any string entirely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do 'lazy' and 'greedy' mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

Comment: @Pointy It's now the same.

Comment: Do you want to have **3** results?

Comment: btw ... what is the desired output/result supposed to look like?

Comment: @luk2302 What change do you suggest I make to get the desired result?

Comment: @Toto yes please

Comment: [Here](https://regex101.com/r/AL4Fyt/1) is a way to go. Caution: it will work for 3 groups only!

Comment: @Toto I need to capture any number of groups, I only used 3 as an example

Comment: A regex can only match distinct substrings. You cannot have one regex that will produce matches which are overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of a capturing group with an infinite quantifier inside a positive lookbehind. See [Lookbehind in JS regular expressions](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind) for the browser support.

```
(?<=(\w+(?:\[\d+])+))(?=\[|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `(` Capture **group 1**

    - `\w+(?:\[\d+])+` Match 1+ word chars, and repeat 1+ times 1+ digits between square brackets
  - `)` Close group
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `(?=\[|$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is either `[` or the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nWR5OB/1)

```js
let regex = /(?<=(\w+(?:\[\d+])+))(?=\[|$)/g;

[
  "hello",
  "hello[0]",
  "hello[0][1]",
  "hello[0][1][3]",
  "hello[0][1][3][2]"
].forEach(s => {
  while ((m = regex.exec(s)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(m[1]);
  }
  console.log("-----------------");
});
```